# PHP_EOL is not working on mac

Tags: php, macos

Can anybody tell me, why `PHP_EOL` is not working on my Mac?

Code:

```
echo 'This is first line'.PHP_EOL.'This is second line';
```

Can any body help me through this?

Comment: How are you looking at the result to determine it's not working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm just going to guess that you're looking at the result *in your browser*, where whitespace is collapsed. PHP may output this:

```
This is first line
This is second line
```

But the browser renders it like this:

> This is first line This is second line

To insert an explicit line break in HTML, use the `<br>` tag.

Comment: +1, if you are outputting HTML from php then it is absolutely fine to use `<br>` tag instead of `PHP_EOL` the only situation you should consider using `PHP_EOL` is when you want to write something to some external files like log files.

Comment: Yes, you are right about what I am getting on my browser. I used '<br />' and worked fine for me. I want to know, why PHP_EOL is not working.

Comment: @Sou `PHP_EOL` ***is*** working, it inserts a line break. But that line break is not honored by the browser. Use View Source to look at the raw PHP output and you'll see your line break.

Comment: @deceze You are right buddy. There I can see the line break. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime you can find this constant undefined, modern hosting with latest php engine do not have this problem but I think that a good thing is write a bit code that saves this situation:

```
<?php
  if (!defined('PHP_EOL')) {
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'WIN')) {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\r\n");
    } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'MAC')) {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\r");
    } elseif (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == 'DAR')) {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\n");
    } else {
      define('PHP_EOL',"\n");
    }
  }
?>
```

So you can use PHP_EOL without problems... obvious that PHP_EOL should be used on script that should work on more systems at once.

PHP_EOL means:

```
1) on Unix    LN    == \n
2) on Mac     CR    == \r
3) on Windows CR+LN == \r\n
```

Hope this answer help.